# My sql getting empty value in table using join table

Tags: php, mysql

How to select all data in first table join with second table print null if dont have table

table 1

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id .           |      name        |  success_img     | unsuccess_img
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     name1 .      |   success        | unsuccess
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     name2 .      |   success        | unsuccess
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

table 2

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id .           |  condition_id    |  member_id       | add_by
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     1 .   .      |   10             | admin
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to out put

table1.id   name    success_img   unsuccess_img member_id add_by

```
  1    name1     success      unsuccess      10      admin

  2    name2     success      unsuccess      null      null
```

I try to use

```
select * from table1 
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where member_id = 10
```

this query it's printing out only name 1 which have member_id = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the where condition to the on clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t2.member_id = 10;
```

Having the check on the `member_id` in the `WHERE` clause was causing the missing record to be filtered off.

Comment: lol you save my day . thank you im thinking about this 2 day haha i'll mark  11 min left